# VBA: Deny long response by using UNC Path and FileSystemObject

Tags: vba, unc, filesystemobject

I try to get a directory which is in the network by using a UNC Path and the FileSystemObject, but if the network directory is not available the response takes so much time. I guess this is because of scanning the a lot of the network and or sends some more pings at this point.
So is there a method which I could use for check faster the exist of a network-directory before using the FSO?

Comment: It's VBA but this does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a file check (and an example of it being called from a subroutine), then a folder check.  Both are called in the same way, and both utilise the `Dir` function.  I added an error handler in the filecheck, it's worth adding this for the folder checker too:

```
Sub Main()
    if FileExists("O:\Filenamehere") = TRUE then
        'do stuff
    end if
End Sub

'For a file
Function FileExists(ByVal FullPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Hand
    If Dir(FullPath) <> "" Then
        FileExists = True
    Else
        FileExists = False
    End If
    Exit Function
Hand:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 52
            FileExists = False
    End Select
End Function

'For a directory
Function DirectoryExists(ByVal FullPath As String) As Boolean
    If Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then DirectoryExists = True Else DirectoryExists = False
End Function
```